# help finding out why users are not being found by the SharePoint people picker

Tags: permissions, people-picker

I have a site foo.com/sites/po. Sites permissions >  selected a group > New > click on the little address book. type in a user last name and click on search icon and I get "No results were found to match your search item. Please enter a new term or less specific term."

However, I have another site foo.com/sites/sale and I dont have this issue. I can search for any user and they are all showing up and i can add them to the sharepoint group.

both are in the same web application. Any idea for this weird behavior and how to get this fixed?

Btw, end users dont have access to powershell so site owners can't add people using powershell

Comment: you can use PowerShell to add users to Group. Thats somewhat easier considering the need to navigate to different pages and settings and perform this addition.